# long poll with node.js and express: how to cache res object into redis or other cache framework

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, redis

I try to build a chat room webpage with node.js/express/redis on the server side.

Following this snips of code :  [A Message Wall With Long Poll Properties in Node.JS and Express](https://gist.github.com/swdunlop/192d8b5e0f00a900cf88) , I succeed to make one node server running correctly. In this example, the `res` objects are saved in a list, no any transformation is needed.

But I want to run the node app with pm2 cluster mode(-i 4),  so I have to save `res` object into some place that shared between 4 nodes.

I already used redis in my node project, for the `express.session`. So I want to cache `res` into redis.

But the problem occured: when I try to sting-lized `res` object with `JSON.stringify(res)`, I got :

`TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

My problem is:

**how could I save one `res` object for later use across node cluster, with redis or something else.**

Appreciate.

---

I use util.inspect to print out my container of res (chatroom_id:res) object:

```
{ '0': null,
  '1390640136999': 
   { domain: null,
     _events: 
      { finish: [Object],
    header: [Function],
    close: [Function: logRequest] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     writable: true,
     _last: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
     sendDate: true,
     _headerSent: false,
     _header: '',
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: false,
     _hangupClose: false,
     socket: 
      { _connecting: false,
    _handle: [Object],
    _readableState: [Object],
    readable: true,
    domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _maxListeners: 10,
    _writableState: [Object],
    writable: true,
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    onend: [Function],
    destroyed: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    bytesRead: 894,
    _bytesDispatched: 0,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: [Object],
    _idleTimeout: 120000,
    _idleNext: [Object],
    _idlePrev: [Object],
    _idleStart: 1390640145289,
    parser: [Object],
    ondata: [Function],
    _paused: false,
    _httpMessage: [Circular],
    _peername: [Object] },
     connection: 
      { _connecting: false,
    _handle: [Object],
    _readableState: [Object],
    readable: true,
    domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _maxListeners: 10,
    _writableState: [Object],
    writable: true,
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    onend: [Function],
    destroyed: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    bytesRead: 894,
    _bytesDispatched: 0,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: [Object],
    _idleTimeout: 120000,
    _idleNext: [Object],
    _idlePrev: [Object],
    _idleStart: 1390640145289,
    parser: [Object],
    ondata: [Function],
    _paused: false,
    _httpMessage: [Circular],
    _peername: [Object] },
     _headers: { 'x-powered-by': 'Express' },
     _headerNames: { 'x-powered-by': 'X-Powered-By' },
     req: 
      { _readableState: [Object],
    readable: true,
    domain: null,
    _events: {},
    _maxListeners: 10,
    socket: [Object],
    connection: [Object],
    httpVersion: '1.0',
    complete: true,
    headers: [Object],
    trailers: {},
    _pendings: [],
    _pendingIndex: 0,
    url: '/robot/chat/query/99/1390640136999/270125/',
    method: 'GET',
    statusCode: null,
    client: [Object],
    _consuming: false,
    _dumped: false,
    httpVersionMajor: 1,
    httpVersionMinor: 0,
    upgrade: false,
    originalUrl: '/robot/chat/query/99/1390640136999/270125/',
    _parsedUrl: [Object],
    query: {},
    res: [Circular],
    next: [Function: next],
    secret: undefined,
    cookies: [Object],
    signedCookies: {},
    sessionStore: [Object],
    sessionID: '4PACUldyCHhT8NgdGY1yz9Pk',
    session: [Object],
    _startTime: Sat Jan 25 2014 16:55:45 GMT+0800 (CST),
    _remoteAddress: '127.0.0.1',
    body: {},
    originalMethod: 'GET',
    _route_index: 2,
    route: [Object],
    params: [Object] },
     locals: [Function: locals],
     end: [Function],
     student_id: '99',
     channel_id: '1390640136999',
     last_msg_id: '270125' } }
```

There are three [Circular].

---

My pseudocode:

```
/*
 * query from http client
 * url: /chat/query/:student_id/:channel_id/:last_msg_id/
 */
exports.query = function(req, res){

    // if find some new msg
        // return them as json, immediately
    // else
        // set participator info into res object
        // read the res_list from redis
        // put this res into res_list
        // write back res_list into redis

};


/*
 * notification from other web server: one new msg been created
 * url: /chat/notify/:new_msg_id/
 */
exports.notify = function(req, res){

    // get new_msg from database by id

    // read the res_list from redis
    // for old_res in res_list
        // if this old_res is releated with the new_msg (participator)
            // old_res.sent(json_content)
            // remove this old_res from res_list
    // write back res_list into redis

};
```

**how could i implement those 'read-and-write-back' part?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: it's not possible to put the `res` object into a cache and obtain it again from another process, in any meaningful way.

If you think about how long poll works, each HTTP client maintains an open connection to the server, waiting (a long time) for something to be sent back. In other words, when you come to push out new messages, you're just sending data down an already open connection. If you cache your `res` into redis, what would happen to the connection?

It may not matter though, as long as you have a way to pass the *content* between your 4 backend processes, they can each update their own set of `res` connections. New connections would still be load balanced.

Comment: thanks for comment. After i cached `res` into redis, it may reach its time out and that connection be closed, or it may be picked out from list and feeded with some response content. As you has pointed out: what I need is **the way to pass the content between processes** or if there is **somehow i can pass the `res` object between processes and use it later**?

Comment: passing the msg content between processes could be one way to achieve my goal, with which the `res` object could be save in the in-memory list within each node processes. Then an msg content queue and feeder-consumer procedure is needed. But there seems to be some trouble that notifying all consumer after one new msg has been created or setting timmer in each cunsumer to check the queue every x seconds. If the `res_list` could be share between processes, it seems to be easier: only one node process needs to be notified and it will do all the jobs. Is it possible?

Comment: There's no way to pass the `res` between processes because the underlying TCP connection which it represents cannot be moved from the process it's connected to. The other stuff is straying into a separate question that I'm not able to answer - I know the network protocols a lot better than the details of node IPC.